# Hibernate pagination - how to get the next batch of results?

Tags: java, hibernate, pagination

I understand pagination to improve performance on queries that, naturally, have a very large resultset.

I have the implemented paginatedList method that successfully returns the correct amount. But it seems more of a MySQL's `LIMIT` or SQLServer's `TOP` clause.

The method is thus implemented:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<T> paginatedList(int pageSize) {
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    criteria.setFirstResult(0);
    criteria.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    return (List<T>) criteria.list();
}
```

And I call like this:

```
@Override
public List<AlertLog> findAll() {
    return super.paginatedList(1000);
}
```

This implementation returns results 0 to 1000.

How to, on runtime, get the 1001st to 2000th and so on?

Comment: set the first result to 1000.

Comment: yes, the idea (and the question was edited) to get the next batch with the application running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the next 1000 result you need to set firstResult to 1000 and maxresults to 1000, so it becomes..

```
criteria.setFirstResult(1000);
criteria.setMaxResults(noOfEntries);
```

Please make sure that the noOfEntries is less that the total count.

Comment: OK, I have considered that. But I'd have to pass the new `criteria.setFirstResult(n)` from the view layer somehow...

Comment: Yes, of course. The backend can't magically guess which page the frontend needs. So it must be a parameter of the request. And an argument of the method.